# Forcing Laravel response status code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a REST API in Laravel and when a new user is created I want to return a 201 status code and a `Location` header to point to the new resource.

Most of that is being achieved using this code:

```
$response = Response::make(null, 201)->header('Location', Config::get('app.url') . '/v1/users/' . $user->id);
return $response;
```

However Laravel seems to be overriding what I set as the status code because I'm setting a `Location` header, as I'm getting a `302 Moved Temporarily` header back.

How can I force a 201 status code even when I'm specifying a `Location` header?

Comment: Fair play for implementing proper response codes. I really don't know why Laravel (which I have huge respect for) doesn't encourage returning "201 Created" for success in the Create method by default. Good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you set the `header()` location, it is overwriting the Laravel response.

If you add 201 status to the `header()` function - it should work I think:

```
$response = Response::make(null, 201)->header('Location', Config::get('app.url') . '/v1/users/' . $user->id, true, 201);
return $response;
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, wasn't aware the `header()` method took those extra parameters.